# UIActivityViewController dismiss MailViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, email

I've try to send an email over the UIActivityViewController and it works fine, but the mail view is not dismissed after the email was send. It also wont't dismiss when the user has pushed the Cancel button.

What can I do to fix the problem?

Here the code I have used:

```
//conf share view
    NSString *textToShare = @"Teststring!";
    UIImage *imageToShare = fetchedImage;
    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:string_url];
    NSArray *activityItems = [[NSArray alloc]  initWithObjects:textToShare, imageToShare,urlToShare,nil];

    UIActivity *activity = [[UIActivity alloc] init];

    NSArray *applicationActivities = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:activity, nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems
                                      applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
        UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
        UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
        UIActivityTypePrint];

    [activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
        NSLog(@"CompletionHandler was called!");
    }];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the solution. You want to present the UIActivityViewController in your fundamental, i.e. your highest or last view controller. In my case, this worked:

```
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try out yourself how many times you have to call parentViewController until you are accessing the highest view controller. In my simple MasterView/DetailView app, I had to call it twice.

Comment: This solved my problem too. To avoid having to count the number of layers, you can add a getRootViewController in your AppDelegate and run: AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.getRootViewController presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I have a UINavigationController inside a modal view controller. No solution seem to work. When the UIActivityViewController is cancelled, a parent view controller gets dismissed and the app becomes unusable! :S

Answer (score 4):

it always come in this completion handler after the posting is done weather it was successfull or not

```
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed)
 {
            if (completed)
     {
         UIAlertView *objalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Posting was successful" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [objalert show];
         objalert = nil;
     }else
     {
         UIAlertView *objalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Posting was not successful" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
         [objalert show];
         objalert = nil;
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

then try to dismiss it on the completitionHandler

```
[activityVC setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
       //Dismiss here 
    }];
```

Comment: I have implemented the delegate Protocol but it is not called. There is no delegate attribute in UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Can you explain a bit better the part of the UIActivityViewController, a bit of code may be helpful

Comment: I've also try this. What I've found out is that if I present the UIActivityViewController in a View with out an UINavigationController everything is okay. But if the view is presented in an UINavigationController it want dismiss.

Comment: And what do you use to dismiss? try [[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: or if (self.presentingViewController) {
                
                [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                
            } else {
                
                [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                
            }

Comment: I have tried both snippets you have posted, but the view still doesn't dismiss it self