# UIActivityController Cancel button doesn't work on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've a problem with the UIActivityController on iOS 8 iPad: the activity view works correctly I can select a share service (i.e. Twitter) but when the "publish" view appear I can only click on the Post button,the Cancel button doesn't work.  I've the same problem on real devices and on the simulator.
If you have an idea about how to fix this problem,...
Thanks
[image]

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)activityController:(id)sender {

// items to share
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:_articleUrl];
NSArray *items=@[url];

// create the controller
        UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:nil];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popPC = controller.popoverPresentationController;
        popPC.barButtonItem = _buttn;
        popPC.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
```

Comment: I know it's not exactly the same problem, but can you see if this solution works for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882198/uiactivityviewcontroller-dismiss-mailviewcontroller It involves changing the view controller on which the `UIActivityViewController` is shown...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work,...

Comment: Did you set the `completionWithItemsHandler` property of your `UIActivityViewController`? From your code, you don't seem to handle anything, but it's your responsibility to show and dismiss the activity view controller and respond to events. See Apple docs on that topic: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/swift/tdef/UIActivityViewControllerCompletionWithItemsHandler